# I need to write this in one line in the listbox what's the best way to do it

Tags: c#, listbox

```
Listbox.Items.Add(Textbox.Text,"name:");
```

I wrote this code but i doesn't seem to do what I want.

Expected result:

> name:abdulrahman

Answer (score 2):

Do you want this?

```
ListBox.Items.Add("name:" + Textbox.Text);
```

Comment: thank you very much but can you give me your WhatsApp number please l need to learn programming with you

Comment: Yes that's true.l want this thank you very much.